# Are gutters the only way to fix this ice accumulation issue?

Tags: drainage, ice

Whenever it rains or snow melts in the winter these rain guards drop water right in front of the walkway which freezes and causes an ice mess. I am reluctant to add a gutter section because no other part of the house has them or run off issues. Might look weird if only one edge of the house has gutters. Was wondering if there's any solutions that don't involve annual maintenance ie cleaning.

[image]

Comment: I think the looks won't be as bad as you think.  I just have gutters on the edges that need them and I never really notice.  Is looks the only concern?  I live in a warm climate.  Do gutters have their own freezing issues?

Comment: @JPhi1618 You ever have any issue with water freezing in the gutters and creating an ice damn leaving the water no where to go?

Comment: @MicahMontoya, you may have seen my comment before the edit - Never had ice, but that's the kind of issue I would worry about for ACD.

Comment: Decently installed gutters shouldn't really call attention to themselves, so I wouldn't worry a whole lot about it looking weird. Anecdotally, a friend of mine has gutters on only one part of their house, and I never noticed for years until I had my own gutters redone and was specifically looking at their setup.

Comment: @JPhi1618 My biggest concern is it's another annual maintenance thing to worry about. Gutters need to be cleaned.

Comment: Just FYI - in my area no way in the world your house is code.   They would at the very very least require gutters near walkways.

Comment: It looks like you are on the west side of a north south street. (From the shadow) . Gutters don't have annual maintenance unless there are trees in the area. In which case a leaf guard for the gutter solves that. But honestly, the look of a  gutter blends in if the color is matched to the house. But given that the last thing you want is for someone to slip on the walkway and sue you, it could be a seasonal addition which can be removed when the weather warms up.

Comment: FYI, that "kicker" is there to prevent water from running behind the siding at the eave as much as it's there for your comfort. Do not remove it. You could shorten it to about a third of what's there if you install a gutter, but leave at least 18" in place to direct the bulk of the water from the wall. You don't want to be replacing wall sheathing, insulation, and the window in 10 years because it all rotted away.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there's a solution that requires no annual maintenance (well, no more than the whole house needs) but that would be to rebuild the roof so it does not dump there. Which you might consider a rather major task, but hey, you asked. Thank the architect for causing the problem for you.

Simplest solution will be a section of gutter and a section of heating cable (run only as needed) to keep the downspout and gutter functional with ice. But you might need to clean it, yes.

Most absurdly expensive solution to operate would be to retrofit ice-melting heat (electric cable or fluid/heat exchanger) into the walkway itself. Truly **crazy expensive** to run, but some places do that.